# development.rb:45:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => Rails.application.secrets[:action_mailer]['default_url_options']['host']}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = Rails.application.secrets[:action_mailer]['delivery_method'].to_sym
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => Rails.application.secrets[:action_mailer]['smtp_settings']['address'],
:domain               => Rails.application.secrets[:action_mailer]['smtp_settings']['domain'],
:port                 => Rails.application.secrets[:action_mailer]['smtp_settings']['port'].to_i,
:user_name            => Rails.application.secrets[:action_mailer]['smtp_settings']['user_name'],
:password             => Rails.application.secrets[:action_mailer]['smtp_settings']['password'],
:authentication       => Rails.application.secrets[:action_mailer]['smtp_settings']['authentication'],
:enable_starttls_auto => eval(Rails.application.secrets[:action_mailer]['smtp_settings']['enable_starttls_auto']), #true or false  }
```

This is the code found in development.rb. I don't know how to fix this error, anyone knows what to do to make smtp configuration work? Below I will write the code from the secret.yml file

```
action_mailer:
 default_url_options:
  host: "localhost:3000"
 delivery_method: "smtp"

smtp_settings:
    address: "smtp.gmail.com"
    domain: "gmail.com"
    port: "587"
    user_name: "my@gmail.com"
    password: "mypassword"
    authentication: :plain
    enable_starttls_auto: "true"
```

I will add that it works on ruby 2.2.0 and rails 4.2.0

Comment: What version of Ruby and Rails give this error?

Comment: Ruby 2.2.0 and Rails 4.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Rails secrets are `:symbol` names, not `'string'` names.

`Rails.application.secrets[:action_mailer][:default_url_options][:host]`

and etc.

`Rails.application.secrets[:action_mailer].keys` will probably return an array of symbols as well. Verify that you're accessing your hashes correctly.

Comment: try hammering out each key in your console and see if it exists. `Rails.application.secrets[:action_mailer]`, then `Rails.application.secrets[:action_mailer][:default_url_options]`, etc.

Comment: I have this command: Rails.application.secrets [: action_mailer] just type in terminal?

Comment: Yeah, it should return a hash.

Comment: there is no such command.  it appeared in the terminal for me